# Why there is no Source Code Management tab in a Jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've just installed the pipeline plugin (on Jenkins 2.1). When I create a new job the *Source Code Management* tab is missing (and a few others).
According to [the article describing the Pipeline feature](https://jenkins.io/2.0/#ux) at it should look like:
[image: Source Code Management tab]

However this is how it looks like in my case:
[image]

Where are the missing tabs, especially the *Source Code Management* one? Is it simply some missing config/plugin or a bug?

I'm on Jenkins 2.1

Comment: The article you linked doesn't just describe the pipeline feature, it shows some changes in 2.0, which isn't exclusively related to pipeline. Those tabs missing in the pipeline job type is intentional, as basically the whole job is defined in the pipeline script, including scm. If you scroll down to pipeline you will see some option to switch between script and Jenkinsfile. In the latter case youll have the option to point some scm to the location of your jenkinsfile.

Comment: Well, I just upgraded from Jenkins 1.6x to 2.1 so I was expecting to see these changes. I saw the option you are referring to although I'm not sure is the repo I'm going to point to for the Jenkinsfile the same as repo of the project I want to build? I kind of have the impression that these are not the same thing. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out. Indeed I had the wrong impression the screen was related to pipeline job.

Comment: Didnt really use Jenkinsfile mechanics yet, i think the repo you put there gets checked out and Jenkinsfile used in there. You could probably also aggregate multiple repo sources from inside the Jenkinsfile if your build needs it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may need to install **Git plugin** (or other SCM connector) before the SCM configuration options will show up. Once it (they) are added to Jenkins, you can continue with the job set up:

In the *Pipeline* section, select **Definition: *Pipeline Script from SCM***. Additional configuration elements will appear on the page, most notably an SCM drop-down selector. Until you install at least one SCM connector plugin (like **Git plugin**), that selector will be empty. (Kinda hard to continue with the configuration without the SCM connector you want...)

Once the SCM connector you want is properly plugged-in, the selector becomes populated with the available SCM options. After choosing the one you want, yet more configuration elements show up - whatever the selected SCM requires.

For example, when using git you will see a **Repository** sub-sub-sub-section where you provide the connection URL and choose an (elsewhere in Jenkins managed) credential. And branch config. And repo-broswer. And more.

After the SCM config bits, there's a configuration of the script file itself, conveniently auto-filled with the default of "Jenkinsfile".

At that point, you should be good to go (presuming you have a `Jenkinsfile` already pushed to the root of your repo).

Comment: So there's no way to configure git for a pipeline, but using a local pipeline script?
My understanding is that I need git scm setup on the job in order for the git webhook support to locate the job and trigger it.

Answer (score 9):

In the Pipeline definition you can select `Pipeline script from SCM`. That will open SCM configuration. Yeah, it's not the most intuitive way.

Comment: does this section only refers to our Jenkinsfile pipeline definition and not to the code and branch that we want to checkout from  the Git??? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The Source Code management tab is available with the Free style project Or Multi- configuration project for the version 2.107.3

Please make sure that when you start a new job you choose right project to see the source code Management tab.
Jenkins > New Item > Free Style Project 
Or
Jenkins > New Item > Multi-Configuration project